# How could we show that $u=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

In my notes there is the following example about the energy method.

We want to show that the problem $$w_{tt}(x, t)-w_{xxtt}(x, t)-w_{xx}(x, t)=f(x, t), 0<x<1, t>0$$ 
$$w(x, 0)=\phi(x) \\ w_t(x, 0)=\psi(x) \\ w_x(0, t)=h(t), t>0 \\ w_x(1, t)=g(t)$$ 
has an unique solution.

We suppose that $w_1, w_2$ are two distinct solutions. Then $u=w_1-w_2$ solves the problem : 
$$u_{tt}(x, t)-u_{xxtt}(x, t)-u_{xx}(x, t)=0, \, 0<x<1, \, t>0$$
$$u(x, 0)=0 \\ u_t(x, 0)=0 \\ u_x(0, t)=0 \\ u_x(1, t)=0$$

$$$$

To find the energy we do the following:

$$\int_0^1(u_tu_{tt}-u_tu_{xxtt}-u_tu_{xx})dx=0 \tag 1$$

$$\int_0^1 u_tu_{tt}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}(u_t^2)_tdx=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}u_t^2dx$$

$$\int_0^1 u_t u_{xxtt}dx=-\int_0^1 u_{tx}u_{xtt}dx+[u_t u_{xtt}]_0^1=-\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}(u_{tx}^2)_tdx$$

$$\int_0^1 u_t u_{xx}dx=-\int_0^1 u_{tx}u_x dx+[u_t u_x]_0^1=-\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^1 u_x^2dx$$

$$(1) \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}u_t^2dx+\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 u_{tx}^2dx+\frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 u_x^2dx=0$$

The energy of the system is $$E(t)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 (u_t^2(x, t)+u_{tx}^2(x, t)+u_{x}^2(x, t))dx$$

$$\Rightarrow E'(t)=\int_0^1 (u_t u_{tt}+u_{tx}u_{xtt}+u_xu_{xy})dx= \dots =0$$

(The energy is always positive.)

$$\Rightarrow 0 \leq E(t) = E(0)=0 \Rightarrow u_t=0 \Rightarrow u(x, t)=u(x, 0)=0 \text{ Contradiction}$$

So,  the initial problem has an inuque solution.

$$$$

---

$$$$
I wanted to apply this at the following :

$$v_{tt}(x, t)-v_{xt}(x, t)=f(x, t), x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0 \\ v(x, 0)=g(x), x \in \mathbb{R} \\ v_t(x, 0)=h(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$$

and I have done the following:

We suppose that $v_1, v_2$ are two distinct solutions. Then $u=v_1-v_2$ solve the problem: 
$$u_{tt}-u_{xt}=0, x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0 \\ v(x, 0)=0, x \in \mathbb{R} \\ v_t=0, x \in \mathbb{R}$$ 
In this case since $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we are looking for the characteristic curves to use them as the limits of the integral.

$$u_{tt}-u_{xt}=f $$ The characteristic curves are $$x=x_0 \text{ AND } x+t=x_0+t_0$$

$$\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}(u_tu_{tt}-u_tu_{xt})dx=0 \tag 2$$

- $$\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}u_tu_{tt}dx=\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\left (\frac{1}{2}u_t^2\right )dx=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}\frac{1}{2}u_t^2dx$$
- \begin{align} 
  \int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}u_tu_{xt}dx &= \int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}u_t\left [\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}u_t\right ]dx=[u_t^2]_{x=x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}-\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}u_{xt}u_tdx \\ &\Rightarrow \int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}u_tu_{xt}dx=\frac{1}{2}\left (u_t^2(x_0+t_0-t, t)-u_t^2(x_0, t)\right )
  \end{align}

$$(2) \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}\frac{1}{2}u_t^2dx-\frac{1}{2}\left (u_t^2(x_0+t_0-t, t)-u_t^2(x_0, t)\right )=0 \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}\frac{1}{2}u_t^2dx=\frac{1}{2}\left (u_t^2(x_0+t_0-t, t)-u_t^2(x_0, t)\right )$$

The energy of the system is $$E(t)=\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}\frac{1}{2}u_t^2dx$$

$$E'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t}\frac{1}{2}u_t^2dx \Rightarrow E'(t)=\frac{1}{2}\left (u_t^2(x_0+t_0-t, t)-u_t^2(x_0, t)\right )$$

We have also that $E(0)=0, E'(0)=0$, right??

How could we continue to show that $u=0$ ?? We could show that if we would know that $E'(t) \leq 0$, but how could we get this inequality??

Answer (score 4):

For the pde $u_{tt} - u_{xt} = 0$, $a \leq x \leq b$, $u(x,0)=0$, $u_{t}(x,0) = 0$ the following  holds
\begin{align}
0 = \int_{a}^{b} u_{t} [ u_{tt} - u_{xt}] \, dx &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{b} \left[ \partial_{t} \left( u_{t}^{2} \right) - \partial_{x} \left( u_{t}^{2} \right) 
\right] \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \partial_{t} \int_{a}^{b} u_{t}^{2} \, dx - u_{t}^{2} \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \partial_{t} \int_{a}^{b} u_{t}^{2} \, dx - \frac{1}{2} \left[ u_{t}^{2}(b,t) - u_{t}^{2}(a,t) \right].
\end{align}
Given the energy in the form
\begin{align}
E(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{a}^{b} u_{t}^{2} \, dx
\end{align}
then the energy is seen to satisfy
\begin{align}
\partial_{t} E(t) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ u_{t}^{2}(b,t) - u_{t}^{2}(a,t) \right].
\end{align}
By using $u_{t}(x,0) = 0$ the energy is conserved at $t=0$ due to
\begin{align}
\left. \partial_{t} E(t) \right|_{t=0} = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain to me why the following holds?? Why is $t=0$ ?? 

$$\frac{1}{2} \left[ \partial_{t} \int_{a}^{b} u_{t}^{2} \, dx - u_{t}^{2} \right] 
= \frac{1}{2} \partial_{t} \int_{a}^{b} u_{t}^{2} \, dx
$$
since $u_{t}(x,0) = 0$ for $a \leq x \leq b$ @Leucippus

Comment: @MaryStar I have modified the result to be more efficient. The boundary conditions given were for $t=0$.

Comment: Can we find out if $E'(t)>0$, $E'(t)<0$ or $E'(t)=0$ , $\forall t>0$ ?? What information do we get from the fact that $E'(0)=0$  @Leucippus

Comment: Or how could we conlcude that $u=0$ ?? @Leucippus

Comment: We could show that $u=0$ if we knew that $E'(t) \leq 0$. But how can we show that $E'(t) \leq 0$ ?? @Leucippus

Comment: @MaryStar As the problem was originally stated the conditions were as stated. From what it appears currently if $u_{t}^{2}(a,t) \geq u_{t}^{2}(b,t)$ then $\partial_{t} E(t) \leq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$E(t)=\int_{x_0}^{x_0+t_0-t} \frac{1}{2} u_t^2 dx$$

From the Fundamental Theorem of Integral Calculus:

$$E'(t)= \frac{1}{2} u_t^2(x_0+t_0-t,t) (x_0+t_0-t)'=\frac{1}{2} u_t^2(x_0+t_0-t,t) (-1) \leq 0$$